# An ice-cream shop sells $11$ kinds of ice-cream, including mango and lemon.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

An ice-cream  shop sells $11$ kinds of ice-cream, including mango and lemon. For a bowl, one chooses at random five kinds (not necessarily different).

$(a)$ How many different bowls can be made? 
 $A=11 \cdot 11\cdot 11\cdot 11\cdot 11$

$(b)$ How many different bowls contain both lemon and mango?
 $A=1 \cdot 1\cdot 11\cdot 11\cdot 11$

$(c)$ How many bowls contain lemon, but not mango?

 $A=1 \cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10$

I don't know if my answers are correct. Can someone explain me this problem please? Thank you.

Comment: For (c), the number of bowls with lemon but not mango is the number without mango minus the number without lemon or mango

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit off.

Let's go with order.

The main question is whether the order of the selection is important or not. That is to say, is a [Mango Mango Mango Lemon Lemon] bowl different than a [Lemon Lemon Mango Mango Mango] one? Let's see how this changes the things

**Question 1: How many possible bowls can exist?**

If the order is important, you are right. There are 11^5 possibilities. More specifically, this is called Permutations (with repetitions) of 11 elements in class 5. In general, the formula for P(n, k) = n^k.

If the order does not matter, then we need to consider how many of those 11^5 are actually duplicated. This is called Combinations (with repetitions) of 11 elements in class 5. In general, the formula for C(n, k) is (n+k-1)! / (k! * (n-1)!) , so in your case that is 15! / (5! * 10!)

**Question 2: How many contain both lemon and mango?**
Well, we need at least 1 mango and 1 lemon, so we can lock those down and then consider the rest as either:
P(11, 3) or C(11, 3) (2 flavors are locked, the rest can be any)

**Question 3: How many contain lemon but not mango?**

Again, we can lock down the lemon, but the other flavors must be anything but mango, so it becomes
P(10, 4) or C(10, 4) (we remove mango from the options for the remaining 4 flavors)

Comment: I don't know if the order matter or not in this problem. That's the way my math teacher gave it. Thank you for explaining me both cases!

Comment: Personally it shouldn't in this particular case, given the context: most people care about the flavors and their quantity, not the order, when you are eating them. But on the other hand some people (me included) are very picky about the order of their ice cream flavors to avoid cross-contamination of the flavors... so.. :D

Comment: Your answer for the combinations interpretation is correct since we may choose more than one scoop of each flavor.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the problem under the assumption that it is the number of scoops of each flavor that matters rather than the order in which the scoops are placed in the bowl.

> How many different bowls can be made?

Let $x_k$ be the number of scoops of flavor $k$.  Then the number of bowls is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_{10} + x_{11} = 5 \tag{1}$$
in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of ten addition signs in a row of five ones.  For instance,
$$+ + 1 + + 1 1 + + 1 + 1 + + +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 2$, $x_6 = 0$, $x_7 = 1$, $x_8 = 1$, $x_9 = x_{10} = x_{11} = 0$.  Thus, the number of such solutions is the number of ways ten addition signs can be inserted into a row of five ones, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 10}{10} = \binom{15}{10}$$
since we must choose which $10$ of the $15$ symbols ($5$ ones and $10$ addition signs) will be addition signs.

> How many different bowls contain both lemon and mango?

Let $x_k$ be defined as above.  Let $x_{10}$ be the number of scoops of lemon; let $x_{11}$ be the number of scoops of mango.  Then $x_{10} \geq 1$ and $x_{11} \geq 1$.  Let $y_{10} = x_{10} - 1$; let $y_{11} = x_{11} - 1$.  Then $y_{10}$ and $y_{11}$ are non-negative integers.  Substituting $y_{10} + 1$ for $x_{10}$ and $y_{11} + 1$ for $x_{11}$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*} 
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + y_{10} + 1 + x_{11} + 1 & = 5\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + y_{10} + y_{11} & = 3 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers.  The number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways we can insert $10$ addition signs in a row of $3$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{3 + 10}{10} = \binom{13}{10}$$
This is equal to the number of bowls with five scoops that contain both lemon and mango since once we place a scoop of each flavor in the bowl, there are three scoops left and eleven flavors (including both lemon and mango) from which to choose those scoops.

> How many different bowls contain lemon but not mango?

Let $x_k$ be defined as above.  Let $x_{10}$ be the number of scoops of lemon; let $x_{11}$ be the number of scoops of mango.  Then $x_{10} \geq 1$ and $x_{11} = 0$.  Let $y_{10} = x_{10} - 1$.  Then $y_{10}$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $y_{10} + 1$ for $x_{10}$ and $0$ for $x_{11}$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + y_{10} + 1 + 0 & = 5\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + y_{10} & = 4 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the non-negative integers.  The number of solutions of equation 3 is the number of ways we can insert $9$ addition signs in a row of $4$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{4 + 9}{9} = \binom{13}{9}$$
This is equal to the number of ways we can fill a bowl that contains lemon but not mango since once we place a scoop of lemon in the bowl, there are four scoops remaining and ten flavors (other than mango) from which to choose them.

Answer (score -1):

You are right if you consider *mango and lemon* to be different from *lemon and mango*.
 I mean to say, *If the order of adding the different components to the ice-cream matters*

Comment: Funny enough, there is kind of a canonical order of putting flavours on an ice-cream cone, which roughly can be described as "the flavour whith the denser texture goes below".